# Letter Missing in PDF Text Extraction

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining, text-extraction, pdfminer

I am beginner python user (Python 3.8.8 mac), and facing the problem of letter missing in the process of pdf to text conversion.

- My Issue:

I tried to extract texts from pdfs and tokenise words in texts. However, some words are missing ending letters such as 'currenc', 'innov', 'sourc' (in the original documents, they are "currency" "innovation" and "source"

- My Attempts:
  I tried pdftotext, pdfminer, pdfminer3, and textract (with language specification method='tesseract'), however none provide the accurate words list (the code is below).The issue is not specific to certain document, but for all documents text extraction.
- Results Sample

'achain',
'blockchain',
'whitepap',
'build',
'boundless',
'tabl',
'content',
'abstract',
'background',
'commit',
'histori',
'network',
'develop',
'need',
'blockchain',
'topic',
'unsolv',
'problem',
'need',
'achain',
'principl',
'stabil',
'safeti',
'scalabl',
'easi',
'use',
'implement',
'smart',
'contract',
'lvm',
'consensu',
'agreement',
'account',
'fork',
'network',
'valu',
'exchang',
'protocol',
'event',
'driven',
'applic',
'suppli',
'chain',
'financ',
'authent',
'develop',
'plan',
'plan',
'program',
'govern',
'achain',
'foundat',
'foundat',
'govern',
'contact',
'us',
'open',
'sourc',
'technic',
'team',
'abstract',

- Code

```
#template of extract text from pdf
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
import io

resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)


def pdf_to_text(filepath):
    print('Getting text content for {}...'.format(filepath))
    process = subprocess.Popen(['pdf2txt.py', filepath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    if process.returncode != 0 or stderr:
        raise OSError('Executing the command for {} caused an error:\nCode: {}\nOutput: {}\nError: {}'.format(filepath, process.returncode, stdout, stderr))

    return stdout.decode('utf-8')

#transform all pdf to csvs
if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_files = list() # a list of dataframes
    for file in pdf:
        csv_file = pdf_to_text(file)
        csv_files.append(csv_file)

#combine all documents(csvs) into one list
documents = []
for i in range(len(csv_files)):
    documents.append(csv_files[i])

# prepare the stopping words from nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
stop = stopwords.words('english')

def mypreprocess(text,n,opt=1):
    # text: document  n: word with length <= n will be ignored  opt: which stemer to use
    text = text.lower()
    # remove all the irrelevant numbers and punctuation
    text = re.sub(r'[^a-z]+',' ',text)
    # tokenize the words
    token = word_tokenize(text)
    # remove the meaningless stopping words
    token = [t for t in token if t not in stop]
    # stemming transformation
   
    if opt == 1:
        token = [porter.stem(t) for t in token]
    else:
        token = [lancaster.stem(t) for t in token]
    token = [x for x in token if len(x) > n]
    return token

tokens = []
for i in range(len(documents)):
    token = mypreprocess(documents[i],1)   # remove irelavant words and stop words, and stem
    tokens.append(token)
    documents[i] = ' '.join(token)
tokens[:50]
```

Comment: "word with length <= n will be ignored" -- perhaps the 'missing' letters were captured as separate 'words' if the distance between letters exceeds some threshold.

Comment: If you only care about the text, I recommend you try [the python fork of tika](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python). I've heard that it sometimes is able to extract text other tools can't, and I personally love its ease of use.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried with tika and changed the tokenization(mypreprocess) part, however still have similar problem...